# How to extend the max length of player list header and footer?

Tags: java, minecraft

I'm making a minecraft plugin for my own server but I have a problem.
I wanted to make player list header and footer with nms (since I'm using version 1.8 for my server).

```
public void setPlayerListHeaderFooter(Player player, String headerName, String footerName) {
    CraftPlayer cp = (CraftPlayer) player;
    PlayerConnection connection = cp.getHandle().playerConnection;

    IChatBaseComponent header2 = IChatBaseComponent.ChatSerializer.a("{'text':'" + headerName + "'}");
    IChatBaseComponent footer2 = IChatBaseComponent.ChatSerializer.a("{'text':'" + footerName + "'}");

    PacketPlayOutPlayerListHeaderFooter packet = new PacketPlayOutPlayerListHeaderFooter();

    try {
        Field header = packet.getClass().getDeclaredField("a");
        header.setAccessible(true);
        header.set(packet, header2);
        header.setAccessible(!header.isAccessible());

        Field footer = packet.getClass().getDeclaredField("b");
        footer.setAccessible(true);
        footer.set(packet, footer2);
        footer.setAccessible(!footer.isAccessible());
    } catch(NoSuchFieldException | IllegalAccessException | DecoderException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    connection.sendPacket(packet);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void setScoreboard(Player player) {

    int playedTime = player.getStatistic(Statistic.PLAY_ONE_TICK) / 72000;
    String hall = plugin.getDataConfig().getString("Player." + player.getUniqueId() + ".hallway");
    int ojPoint = plugin.getDataConfig().getInt("Player." + player.getUniqueId() + ".onejump");

    Scoreboard sb = Bukkit.getScoreboardManager().getNewScoreboard();
    Objective object = sb.registerNewObjective("hpkNetwork", "dummy");
    object.setDisplayName(sbName);
    object.setDisplaySlot(DisplaySlot.SIDEBAR);

    Score line1 = object.getScore(ChatColor.GRAY + "" + ChatColor.STRIKETHROUGH + "-+------------------+-");
    line1.setScore(15);

    Score hallRank = object.getScore(ChatColor.RED + "" + ChatColor.BOLD + "Hallway");
    hallRank.setScore(14);

    Team HallwayRank = sb.registerNewTeam("hallway");
    HallwayRank.setPrefix("" + ChatColor.GRAY + "» ");
    HallwayRank.addEntry(ChatColor.YELLOW + "");
    HallwayRank.setSuffix(ChatColor.WHITE + hall);
    object.getScore(ChatColor.YELLOW + "").setScore(13);

    Score blank2 = object.getScore("  ");
    blank2.setScore(12);

    Score ojRank = object.getScore(ChatColor.GOLD + "" + ChatColor.BOLD + "OneJump Points");
    ojRank.setScore(11);

    Team oj = sb.registerNewTeam("onejump");
    oj.addEntry(ChatColor.DARK_AQUA + "");
    oj.setPrefix("" + ChatColor.GRAY + "» " + ChatColor.WHITE + ojPoint);
    object.getScore(ChatColor.DARK_AQUA + "").setScore(10);

    Score blank3 = object.getScore("   ");
    blank3.setScore(9);

    Score played = object.getScore(ChatColor.YELLOW + "" + ChatColor.BOLD + "PlayTime");
    played.setScore(8);

    Team playTime = sb.registerNewTeam("played");
    playTime.addEntry(ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE + "");
    if (playedTime < 2) {
        playTime.setSuffix("" + ChatColor.GRAY + "» " + ChatColor.WHITE + playedTime + " hour");
    } else {
        playTime.setSuffix("" + ChatColor.GRAY + "» " + ChatColor.WHITE + playedTime + " hours");
    }
    object.getScore(ChatColor.LIGHT_PURPLE + "").setScore(7);

    Score blank4 = object.getScore("    ");
    blank4.setScore(6);

    Score jumpCount = object.getScore("" + ChatColor.GREEN + "" + ChatColor.BOLD + "JumpCount");
    jumpCount.setScore(5);

    Team jumpCounter = sb.registerNewTeam("jumpCounter");
    jumpCounter.addEntry(ChatColor.GRAY + "» ");
    jumpCounter.setSuffix(ChatColor.WHITE + "" + player.getStatistic(Statistic.JUMP));
    object.getScore(ChatColor.GRAY + "» ").setScore(4);

    Score line2 = object.getScore(ChatColor.GRAY + "" + ChatColor.STRIKETHROUGH + "-+------------------+- ");
    line2.setScore(3);

    Score serverIP = object.getScore("§eplay.hpknetwork.xyz");
    serverIP.setScore(2);

    Team tab = sb.registerNewTeam("tab");

    for (Player online: Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
        if (hall == null) {
            tab.setPrefix("§8[§a+§8] §b[ §f1 §b] ");
        } else {
            tab.setPrefix(hall + " ");
        }
        tab.addEntry(online.getName());

        tab.setNameTagVisibility(NameTagVisibility.ALWAYS);
        tab.addPlayer(online);
    }

    player.setScoreboard(sb);
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void updateScoreboard(Player player) {

    int playedTime = player.getStatistic(Statistic.PLAY_ONE_TICK) / 72000;
    String hall = plugin.getDataConfig().getString("Player." + player.getUniqueId() + ".hallway");
    int ojPoint = plugin.getDataConfig().getInt("Player." + player.getUniqueId() + ".onejump");

    Scoreboard board = player.getScoreboard();
    board.getTeam("onejump").setPrefix("" + ChatColor.GRAY + "» " + ChatColor.WHITE + ojPoint);
    board.getTeam("jumpCounter").setSuffix(ChatColor.WHITE + "" + player.getStatistic(Statistic.JUMP));
    board.getTeam("hallway").setSuffix(ChatColor.WHITE + hall);

    if (playedTime < 2) {
        board.getTeam("played").setSuffix(ChatColor.GRAY + "» " + ChatColor.WHITE + playedTime + " hour");
    } else {
        board.getTeam("played").setSuffix(ChatColor.GRAY + "» " + ChatColor.WHITE + playedTime + " hours");
    }

    for (Player online: Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers()) {
        if (hall == null) {
            board.getTeam("tab").setPrefix("§8[§a+§8] §b[ §f1 §b] ");
        } else {
            board.getTeam("tab").setPrefix(hall + " ");
        }
        board.getTeam("tab").addPlayer(online);
    }

}`

@EventHandler
public void joinScoreboard(PlayerJoinEvent event) {

    Player player = event.getPlayer();
    setScoreboard(player);
    setPlayerListHeaderFooter(player, "§d§lHpk§f§lNetwork\n", "\n    §eplay.hpknetwork.xyz    ");

    new BukkitRunnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                updateScoreboard(player);
            } catch(NullPointerException | DecoderException ignored) {

            }
        }

    }.runTaskTimer(plugin, 0, 1);


}
```

But if I set header or footer over 15 length, when I join the server first time, I got DecoderException.

[DecoderException](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TY7w2.png)

So I wonder how to extend the max length of player list header and footer.

Comment: That was fine without all the scoreboard part. It's better if the code is minimal, here there is too much code ^^'

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

With scoreboard, we can add suffix/prefix with the score itself to reach 48 char, but not here.

You have to split the string at 16 char. You can do it with `String.substring(0, 16)` like that:

```java
public void setPlayerListHeaderFooter(Player player, String headerName, String footerName) {
    CraftPlayer cp = (CraftPlayer) player;
    PlayerConnection connection = cp.getHandle().playerConnection;

    IChatBaseComponent header = IChatBaseComponent.ChatSerializer.a("{'text':'" + limitTo(headerName, 16) + "'}");
    IChatBaseComponent footer = IChatBaseComponent.ChatSerializer.a("{'text':'" + limitTo(footerName, 16) + "'}");

    PacketPlayOutPlayerListHeaderFooter packet = new PacketPlayOutPlayerListHeaderFooter(header);

    try {
        Field footer = packet.getClass().getDeclaredField("b");
        footer.setAccessible(true);
        footer.set(packet, footer);
        footer.setAccessible(!footer.isAccessible());
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    connection.sendPacket(packet);
}

private String limitTo(String s, int max) {
   return max.lenghth() > s ? : max.substring(0, max) : s;
}
```

Comment: Oh, I saw some 1.8 minecraft servers are using the footer with over 16 like this.
https://imgur.com/a/wipNvSI

I wonder how they did it.

Comment: this is footer ? it seems to be scoreboard

Comment: Also, are you login with more than 1.13 client ? because in 1.13+ the limit change

Comment: sometimes, but I often use 1.8.9